# Electron: How to store data in cache manually

Tags: reactjs, file, electron

I'm seeing a lot of info about clearing the cache on **electron** app, but not about **how to save the data in cache.**

This is where the data is cached:

```
Linux: $XDG_CACHE_HOME or ~/.cache/electron/
MacOS: ~/Library/Caches/electron/
Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%/electron/Cache or ~/AppData/Local/electron/Cache/
```

And there are binary files in this location.

Is there a way to **save** the file in this path?

Comment: *How to save **the** file in this path?* What file? What's different than writing to any other destination (the OS you can detect and thus could also choose the right path at runtime); do you have any problems? Also, why use Electron's cache? Wouldn't it be better to save any temporary file into a temporary directory for which all OSes have facilities OOTB?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I don't know if that was the OP's intent, but some of us are behind corporate proxies and the electron installation script fails to download the binaries. That's why they describe here how to bypass the download and create the cache manually:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/installation#custom-mirrors-and-caches

Answer (score 0):

If you're behind a corporate proxy like I am, and you want to create the cache manually as described in https://www.electronjs.org/docs/v14-x-y/tutorial/installation#custom-mirrors-and-caches, just use a private, unrestricted laptop to install electron in a test app, and then copy the cache folder to your actual corporate machine. It is too much trouble to do it manually on your own.

Comment: The url has been changed to https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/installation#custom-mirrors-and-caches